# VBA Excel, Array contains invalidly a zero value

Tags: excel, vba

Idea of my code is that I want to store a row number in an array where is the text `"AnchorPointStartDontDelete"`

Code

```
Set rightRng = Range(Cells(8, 10), Cells(ER.row - 1, 10))
Dim arr() As Long
ReDim arr(1 To 1) As Long

For Each rng In rightRng
    If rng.value = "AnchorPointStartDontDelete" Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) + 1) As Long

        Debug.Print rng.row

        arr(UBound(arr)) = rng.row
    End If
Next rng
```

`Debug.Print rng.row` of my range is the following like below, but I cannot fathom where the zero value comes from, because `rng` is from `row 8 to ER.Row`

0 
 8 
 11 
 13 
 14 
 16 
 18 
 22 
 26 
 33 
 34 
 36 
 38 
 40 
 43 
 46 
 41 
 46

Corrected code --> Leaves zero value as a last in the array and then I delete it.

```
  For Each rng In rightRng
    If rng.value = "AnchorPointStartDontDelete" Then

        arr(UBound(arr)) = rng.row
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) + 1) As Long
    End If

Next rng


' Code line below delete the last value
ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) - 1) As Long
```

Comment: Regardless of where you start, `Range.Row` is never a zero. Step through your code with F8.

Comment: Switch the two lines of code `ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) + 1) As Long` and `arr(UBound(arr)) = rng.row`. Then everything should be fine. If you don't want to have a `0` at the end then you should also add `ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) - 1) As Long` to the **end** of your code.

Comment: @Ralph `Debug.Print rng.row` does not take values from the array.

Comment: @GSerg Yes, I know. So? What's your point?

Comment: @Ralph My point is that you are talking about removing the zero from the array whereas the printed values do not come from the array.

Comment: @GSerg Doesn't matter. Still, the resulting array (`debug.print` or not) will have a `0` element at the end. So, if AratioD wants to remove that element then he / she can remove it with the given line. I don't care about `Debug.Print`. I merely look at the resulting array.

Comment: @Ralp,  `ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) - 1) As Long`, this piece code did the magic, but just wondering why there is a zero in my array, because I don't input that into array.

Comment: Whenever you issue the command `ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) + 1) As Long` the array is increased by one element. But the new element is not assigned a value. So, VBA automatically assigns it the default value (for long) of `0`.

Comment: Aah, that make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You start with an array of 1 element, so before entering the loop, you have `arr(1) = 0`. Then you enter the loop the first time and immediatly increase the size of `arr`, so now `ubound(arr) = 2` and you write the row of the first hit into element 2.

You should avoid doing too many `Redim Preserve` as it is very expensive.
The following code reduces the number of Redims.

```
Const size = 100 

Dim arr() As Long, cnt As Long
ReDim arr(1 To size)
cnt = 0

For Each rng In rightRng
    If rng.Value = "AnchorPointStartDontDelete" Then
        cnt = cnt + 1
        If cnt > UBound(arr) Then ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) + size)
        arr(cnt) = rng.Row
    End If
Next rng
ReDim Preserve arr(1 To cnt)
```

Comment: `Debug.Print rng.row` does not take values from the array.

Comment: @Gserg: You are right. On the other hand, the problem keeping 0 in the first element will exists anyhow